# Create a regex to find queries separated by a semicolon or a space, similar to how GitHub Search works

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to create a regex to catch the values of qualifier: value pairs, similar to how it's done in [GitHub Search](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax)

As an example:

`project name: foo/bar, foo/bar; status: online, offline; user: test location: Spain, Italy`

A semicolon or space can be used to separate each `qualifier:value` pair.

Furthermore, each value can have multiple parameters separated by commas:

`status: online, offline`

The goal is to capture the specific qualifier's concrete value.

My current solution is as follows:

```js
function getMatch(qualifier, string) {
    var formattedStr = string.replace(/ \/ | \/|\/ /g, "/");

    const regex = new RegExp(`${qualifier}:[\\s]?([,/A-Za-z0-9_-]*)[;\\s]?`, "g");
    var match = (formattedStr.match(regex) || []).map((e) =>
        e.replace(regex, "$1")
    );
    console.log(match)
}
```

However, if the value contains multiple parameters separated by commas, it will only catch the first occurrence:

For `status: online, offline` it will catch the value `online` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a space character in your character class here: `[,/A-Za-z0-9_-]`

Also, you can make your life a bit better by using a letter wildcard `\w` instead of the `A-Za-z0-9` bit.

Here's my tweaked version:
https://regexr.com/6ok61